# How do you make object follow user controlled object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So currently, I have a simple square which I can move around the canvas with the arrow keys. I'm trying to figure out how to add another square that is NOT controlled by the user, but instead, follows the user controlled square until it touches it. So, I am essentially trying to make a square that chases the user controlled square. So far, this is the code for my user controlled square.

```
    $(function () {
    var pane = $('#pane'),
    box = $('#box'),
    wh = pane.width() - box.width(),
    wv = pane.height() - box.height(),
    d = {},
    x = 5;

    function newh(v,a,b) {
        var n = parseInt(v, 10) - (d[a] ? x : 0) + (d[b] ? x : 0);
        return n < 0 ? 0 : n > wh ? wh : n;
    }

    function newv(v,a,b) {
        var n = parseInt(v, 10) - (d[a] ? x : 0) + (d[b] ? x : 0);
        return n < 0 ? 0 : n > wv ? wv : n;
    }

    $(window).keydown(function(e) { d[e.which] = true; });
    $(window).keyup(function(e) { d[e.which] = false; });

    setInterval(function() {
        box.css({
            left: function(i,v) { return newh(v, 37, 39); },
            top: function(i,v) { return newv(v, 38, 40); }
        });
        wh = pane.width() - box.width();
        wv = pane.height() - box.height();
    }, 100);
    });
```

I can add many other squares into this by copying the code in her and the divs in the html/css, but the still move based on my click. How do I make them move without it?

Comment: Your nested ternaries hurt my eyes

Comment: @SterlingArcher shut up they're beautiful and need love